# How to get the same salted password in Java as by using openssl passwd?

Tags: java, openssl, cryptography, md5, saltedhash

What I need is to get the same result as:

```
# openssl passwd -1 -salt SaltSalt thesecretpassword
$1$SaltSalt$d4KyTrYpU26ghRyvibVDY0
```

At least the last part(**d4KyTrYpU26ghRyvibVDY0**), as the first two parts are fixed to $1$SaltSalt$.

This is needed, so it can be set for a password of a Linux user.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* You might want to [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). In the meantime, maybe [Rent A Coder](http://www.rentacoder.com) or [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com) can help you out.

Comment: @jww This seems like a perfectly valid question to me. It is clear what the problem is and it is not immediately obvious that `$1$` needs to be appended to the salt to make a function like `Crypt.crypt` give the expected output. Which library is used is in this case, only a circumstantial part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it in [commons-codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Crypt.html#crypt(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

Crypt.crypt(password, String.format("$1$SaltSalt", "thesecretpassword"))